# TFS Build -Error CS1002: ; expected and Error CS1519 Invalid token

Tags: c#, tfs, build, token

I built my solution properly in Visual Studio, but when I build with TFS, I have several errors such as:

```
path\file.cs (8, 47)
path\file.cs(8,47): Error CS1002: ; expected
path\file.cs (8, 85)
path\file.cs(8,85): Error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
```

Screen: [image]

```
namespace path
{
    public class file : Ifile
    {
        public IContactService ContactService => Locator.GetService<IContactService>();
        public IAddressService AddressService => Locator.GetService<IAddressService>();
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: You don't think we need to see the code in file.cs to help you out? Does it even compile in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes it compiles properly in Visual Studio.

Comment: I edited my first message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public IContactService ContactService => Locator.GetService<IContactService>();
```

This is an [expression-bodied property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx) and is implemented only in CSC 6 and later. Your TFS is probably running CSC 5 or earlier. You have to change it to:

```
public IContactService ContactService
{
    get { return Locator.GetService<IContactService>(); }
}
```

Comment: I'm using this version of TFS: Version 15.105.25910.0
What is CSC, and how can I modify this, thank you very much, I,m a novice in TFS.

Comment: CSC is the C# compiler and has little to do with the version of TFS. Your version of TFS looks recent; you may only need to [change MSBuild command in TFS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/deabf486-b3dc-4819-a845-ac575bf3f84b/tfs-build-using-wrong-visual-studio-version?forum=tfsbuild).

Comment: If I add asargument MSBUILD on TFS /tv:14.0 /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0, I have now these errors; the process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code 1